# Transform bank identification number into account number

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

I have a problem, I need to translate a peace of javascript code (that transforms the bank identification number to account number) into objective-c.
The problem is that I'm still very new to objective-c and I don't know anything about javascript...

Here is the javascript code:

```
if (banco == "CGD"){
banco_num=str2bigInt('0035',10,6,21);
NIB_aux=mult(banco_num,str2bigInt('100000000000000000',10,6,21));
str_conta_banco = document.conta_banco.conta.value;

if(isNaN(str_conta_banco) || str_conta_banco.length!=13){
    alert("Invalid account number");
    return;
}
var conta_num = str2bigInt(str_conta_banco,10,6,21);

var conta_sem_balcao = mod(conta_num,str2bigInt('1000000000',10,6,21)); 
var balcao = sub(conta_num,conta_sem_balcao);

conta_sem_balcao = mult(conta_sem_balcao,str2bigInt('100',10,6,21));
balcao = mult(balcao,str2bigInt('10000',10,6,21));

NIB_aux=add(NIB_aux,add(balcao,conta_sem_balcao));

NIB_ref=sub(str2bigInt('98',10,6,21),mod(NIB_aux,str2bigInt('97',10,6,21)));

NIB=add(NIB_aux,NIB_ref);  
NIB_str="00"+bigInt2str(NIB,10);

document.write("<center>O seu NIB &eacute;: "+NIB_str+"<br></br></center>");
return;
```

}

I have made some attempts but after 3 hours I gave up...can't figure out the "str2bigInt", "isNaN" etc...

Any kind soul to give me some guidance I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str2bigInt() is not a javascript built-in function. Therefore it doesn't make part of your code and that's why you get undefined error for it. Javascript stops after that error.

Comment: I know I was trying with "Str2int" dunno if the same thing :)